# instaR http error 400, can't get access token

Tags: r, oauth, instagram, http-status-code-400, httr

i've been trying to use instaR, but failed at getting an access token - getting the response:

> Authentication complete.
>
> Error in init_oauth2.0(self$endpoint, self$app, scope = self$params$scope, :
>
> Bad Request (HTTP 400). Failed to get an access token.

when examining the request using with_verbose(), i don't see any additional info.

```
httr::with_verbose(my_oauth <- instaOAuth(app_id=client_id,app_secret=client_secret))
```

this is the response i get (masked the client id and secret):

> Waiting for authentication in browser...
>   Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
>
> Authentication complete.
>
> POST /oauth/access_token HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: api.instagram.com
>
> User-Agent: libcurl/7.43.0 r-curl/2.2 httr/1.2.1
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> Cookie: csrftoken=oLgx7eQh8uZH1ZWMl53lC2y0JJWQkmwd
>
> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, /
>
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> Content-Length: 206
>
> client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1410%2F%2F&grant_type=authorization_code&code=98e38f8c53354a22bd3786f96cd19e3e&client_secret=[CLIENT_SECRET]
>
> <- HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
>
> <- Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
>
> <- Vary: Cookie, Accept-Language
>
> <- Content-Language: en
>
> <- Date: Mon, 21 Nov 2016 00:27:48 GMT
>
> <- Content-Type: application/json
>
> <- Pragma: no-cache
>
> <- Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
>
> <- Set-Cookie: csrftoken=oLgx7eQh8uZH1ZWMl53lC2y0JJWQkmwd; expires=Mon, 20-Nov->2017 00:27:48 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; Secure
>
> <- Connection: keep-alive
>
> <- Content-Length: 114
>
> <-
>
> Error in init_oauth2.0(self$endpoint, self$app, scope = self$params$scope, :
>
> Bad Request (HTTP 400). Failed to get an access token.

i saw people reporting similar issues with R FB libraries, some of them reported that reverting to an older httr version resolved the issue (due to the current version possibly having some issues with http instead of https requests). i tried both the current version and 1.1.0 with the same results.

> R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
>   Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
>   Running under: OS X 10.11.1 (El Capitan)
>
> locale:
>   [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
>
> attached base packages:
>   [1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base
>
> other attached packages:
>   [1] instaR_0.2.4 jsonlite_1.1 httr_1.2.1
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>   [1] R6_2.1.2 tools_3.2.3 withr_1.0.1 curl_2.2 memoise_1.0.0 Rcpp_0.12.4 >git2r_0.14.0 digest_0.6.9 httpuv_1.3.3
>   [10] devtools_1.11.1

found some interesting info at https://github.com/hadley/httr/issues/379, but no solution.

any help would be greatly appreciated!